# Yii2 RESTful API - use custom XML schema with attributes

Tags: xml, rest, xsd, yii2

I already a created a working RestController with Authentication and custom Actions.

To display the required information I used the fields method in the model like so:

```
public function fields()
{
    return [
        'title',
        'description',
        'street',
        'postalcode',
        'city',
        'url' => function () {
            return 'https://someurl.com/';
        },
    ];
}
```

The Action returns a XML Response with this Schema:

```
<response>
    <title>The title</title>
    <description>Some text</description>
    <street>Streetname</street>
    <postalcode>Postalcode</postalcode>
    <city>City</city>
    <url>https://someurl.com/</url>
</response>
```

But I would like to use a specific/nested XML Schema to use the response in another system. This could look like the following:

```
<real_estate>
    <object_information>
        <title>The title</title>
        <description>Some text</description>
    </object_information>
    <geo>
        <street>Streetname</street>
        <postalcode>Postalcode</postalcode>
        <city>City</city>
    </geo>
    <url>https://someurl.com/</url>
</real_estate>
```

How do I create such a XML Scheme with custom field names and nested elements?

Comment: How about just using `multidimensional array` in return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Yupik! I could achieve a solution with the following code:

```
public function fields()
{

    return [
        'object_information' => function($model) {
            return [
                'title' => $model->title,
                'description' => $model->description
            ];
        },
        'geo' => function ($model) {
            return [
                'street' => $model->street,
                'postalcode' => $model->postalcode,
                'city' => $model->city,
            ];
        },
        'url' => function ($model) {
            return 'https://someurl.com/';
        },
    ];
}
```